# Issue with performSegueWithIdentifier - No error, but nothing happens

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am new to storyboard and I am trying to hook up some segues to be called programmatically.

Basically my app uses websockets to connect to a server and then shows content based on messages received from the server.

So the first scene in my app is just a "Connecting..." screen that will show until it has successfully connected to my server.
Once it connects, I need it to show the next screen.

Here is my storyboard:
[image]

When the app connects to the server, the server sends a message asking for the client type (the same server will be used for a mobile website and android app).

The app listens for this message, then replies to the server saying that it is an iPhone.
When the server is ready for the client to login, it sends a "loginready" message.

This is the only code I have gotten to work to switch to the login screen:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *loginVC = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];

    [mViewController presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But it takes it (the simulator at least... subscription ran out a few weeks ago) a good 15 seconds to make the transition.

I originally tried this:

```
[mViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {
    [mViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:segueID sender:mViewController];
}];
```

Where `mViewController` is the `UIViewController` of the current scene, but this did absolutely nothing.. As in, it just stayed on the "Connecting..." page with no errors or any evidence that any code had been ran.

I also tried this code to move to the third scene after the server sends a "logintrue" message, and the login screen dismisses, but only to reveal the "Connecting..." screen and never to transition to the third scene.

I don't really mind if I have to use the `presentViewController` technique, but only if I can make it not so damn slow.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the server callback that you're making? Are you using a completion block, and waiting for the block to call before attempting to segue? UIKit could be hanging because you're taking up the main thread...